# Is there a root folder I can access in Azure File Storage?

Tags: azure-storage

I am accessing Azure File Storage from Silverlight and I need to upload/create a crossdomain.xml file at the root of the storage:

https://[account].file.core.windows.net/crossdomain.xml

Seen many example for blob on this but I can't seem to create a $root for the file storage (without adding a file share).

Silverlight requires a crossdomain.xml at the root level to use the Azure REST API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure File Storage [follows the "share-directory" structure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/). I am not aware about any Root folder (i know about crossdomain and the requirements) in Azure File Storage and i believe it can not be done with the File Storage.

You can invoke

```
CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference()
```

which returns the share root directory, but not File Storage one.

For being able to implement what you need i would recommend you to switch to Blob Storage if there are no specific requirements that need File Storage.

Comment: Thanks Alex, by getting a reference to the root as you describe it is possible to add the crossdomain file.

Answer (score 1):

The comment section did not allow to that much characters. Therefore, I've posted this as an answer which in fact is not a solution :).

The following is my experience which I've wanted to share.

I have tried to add a crossdomain file into the root but could not succeed. The code is as follows:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(getConnectionString());

CloudFileClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare share = client.GetShareReference(shareName);
CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

var crossDomainFile = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("crossdomain.xml");

if (!crossDomainFile.Exists())
{
    crossDomainFile.UploadText(getCrossDomainXmlContent());
    Console.WriteLine("crossDomainFile.StorageUri:" + crossDomainFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri);
}
```

share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("crossdomain.xml") which gives you this address: 
https://[account].file.core.windows.net/<share name>/crossdomain.xml.

For Silverlight or flash clients, the file must reside at https://[account].file.core.windows.net/crossdomain.xml.

Using blob storage instead of file is a better choice, it seems.

Also creating a cloud file object by giving a URI like https://[account].file.core.windows.net/crossdomain.xml is also useless. When you call UploadText method (example: crossDomainFile.UploadText(getCrossDomainXmlContent()), you get 400 - Bad Request error.